# How to make Vue 3 UI library tree-shakable?

Tags: javascript, build, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vite

I have an UI library made with Vuetify. It bundles up to 1,8Mb and the problem is that not all the projects utilize everything from it, and it is also bundle everything into index.js and it is quite obvious that I don't need everything at same time as the app loads.

Here is the sceenshot of the app build result:
[image]

It is very clear that my app is only ~200Kb, while most of the bundle size is the UI lib.

The library config is quite simple:

```
/components
  ...some components
  index.ts // export all components via this

package.json
vite.config.ts
```

package.json

```
  "type": "module",
  "main": "dist/design-system.cjs.js",
  "module": "dist/design-system.es.js",
  "types": "dist/entry.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": {
        "types": "./dist/entry.d.ts",
        "default": "./dist/design-system.es.js"
      },
      "require": "./dist/design-system.cjs.js"
    },
    "./dist/style.css": "./dist/entry.css",
    "./src/assets/*": "./src/assets/*"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "src/assets/**"
  ],
```

Build config:

```
baseConfig.build = {
  cssCodeSplit: true,
  lib: {
    formats: ['cjs', 'es'],
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/entry.ts'),
    name: 'DesignSystem',
    fileName: (format) => `design-system.${format}.js`,
  },
  rollupOptions: {
    external: [
      'vue',
      'vuetify',
      'vuetify/components',
      'vuetify/directives',
      'vuetify/types/services/goto',
      'date-fns',
      'date-fns/locale',
    ],
    output: {
      dir: 'dist',
      exports: 'named',
      globals: {
        vue: 'Vue',
      },
    },
    plugins: [
      typescript({
        target: 'esnext',
        rootDir: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        declaration: true,
        declarationDir: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        exclude: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/**'),
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/tests/**'),
        ],
        allowSyntheticDefaultImports: true,
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```

So, the question is how to make the library tree-shakable?

Comment: You can inspect the package with a tool like [rollup-plugin-visualizer](https://github.com/btd/rollup-plugin-visualizer) to find out what takes up so much space. If you are sure it is Vuetify, please add the plugin config (where you run `createVuetify()`) to the question.